# Includepaths for Qt-headers on Windows using msvc compiler

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I tried to set up my Qt-Creator together with the MSVC compiler. It took a while to set up the PATH, but it's finally working. The only problem i have is, that i have to specify every single INCLUDEPATH, by either putting it into the .pro file and including like normal:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore\
#include <QtGlobal>
```

Or by going back one step and specifying the exact path in the .cpp include:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\
#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>
```

I already added the following line, which seems to do nothing for me (doesn't compile with the missing INCLUDEPATH tho):

```
QT += core
```

I work with the gcc compiler and Qt Creator at work and i can simply include with:

```
QT += core
#include <QtGlobal>
```

And i don't need to specify the exact INCLUDEPATH anywhere. I tried adding the INCLUDEPATH to my PATH environment-variable, but it does not seem to fix my problem.

How can I specify the location of the Qt-Headers in QtCreator without having to write the whole path in the .pro file or the base folder in the includes?

Comment: Have you set it up under `Qt Creator > Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits`? http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html

Comment: `INCLUDEPATH` is not an environment variable!!

Comment: I know that INCLUDEPATH is not an environment variable, but PATH is. I added the INCLUDEPATH to the .pro file.

Comment: @phyatt The Build&Run components are already properly set up. I can use qmake and i can use the c++ standard library, just the #includes are not working properly for the Qt Headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the answer is rather stupid.

The project I was testing with was an old one from my private repository and appareantly I created it as a non Qt-Project. The .pro file contained this line:

```
CONFIG -= qt
```

Which simply excluded all the Qt Headers.